# Set freestyle job result to FAILED with "Execute groovy script" build step

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have tried so many things to set the job status to FAILED without printing a stack trace. Nothing works because it seems the "Execute groovy script" step has no access to any of the job variables. For several reasons, I cannot use "Execute system groovy script". How do I do this?

currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: currentBuild for class: hudson4756676730102994092

build.@result = 'FAILED'
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: build for class:
hudson7411676143395659493

exit(1)
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson4931461189946955208.exit() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1]

return 1
Finished: SUCCESS

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

System.exit(1)

I had consciously avoided that answer because in other jobs it causes Jenkins itself to shut down. But, since this is not system groovy code, it just exits the groovy script with an error code.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins will **always fail** the build (and throw an exception) for any **non zero exit code** - and that cannot be changed.

**For example:**
If you're using something like python you can do a "raise" in a try{}catch{} block to see the error and fail the build. *(subprocess.check_call is great with Jenkins and raise will return an non-zero exit code to fail the job properly.)*

In Jenkins jobs directly I'll call "System.exit(1)" to fail the build in test jobs to see plugins interactions.

Comment: I already know about pipelines. But I specifically said these are freestyle jobs. Also, any time you throw an exception, it will print a stack trace.

Comment: Ah, sorry my comment was supposed to be generalized to Jenkins and not pipeline I've edited Pipeline out of the non-zero exit code statement. As for the python example - it's how I set it up in both freestyle and pipeline.